# ng-include Stopped working after update to 1.2.0rc1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

Yesterday when I was using older version, everything worked fine. My code looked like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in widgets" class="box" ng-include="widget.view"></div>
```

Today I updated to newer version and it seems that it doesn't work anymore. I tried different versions of how to use ng-include and this one below renders a comment where the content should be:

Comment:

```
<!-- ngInclude: widget.view -->
```

Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in widgets" class="box">
    <ng-include src="widget.view"></ng-include>
</div>
```

I've also tried moving views out of partials into script tags but it doesn't help. Before I moved to script tag there was SUCCESSFUL xhr request to partial, but it just didn't render it.

What could be wrong?

**Edit:** if I change version back without any code modification, everything works again.

Comment: "rc1" means "Release Candidate 1" means "proceed with caution".

Comment: @Stewie I understand this, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. If I'm  not I will open an Issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly it's this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627 foo bar foo bar